# Powershell log tailer issues

Tags: regex, xml, powershell

I have written a log tailer with Powershell, the tailer loads in an xml file which contains configuration information regarding when to report on a word match in the log tail (basically if certain patterns occur X amount of times in the tail).

At the moment the tailer is not returning matches for many of the lines that contain matches.

For example we are retrieving a log file with many INFO lines, if I check for the word INFO nothing is detected, however if I look for the work shutdown it returns matches (the line with shutdown also contains INFO on the line).

The really strange thing is that using the same log file and same Powershell script seems to produce perfectly accurate results on my own machine but behaves strangely on the server.

I suspect that this might be an issue with the version of Powershell that is running on the server, so I was hoping someone here might know of issues that can come up with different versions. I have also noticed that when I print out the number of matches, if nothing is found the output is blank, perhaps this should be 0 and is causing some weird issue to trigger?

```
function Main()
{
    #### GLOBAL SETTINGS

    $DebugPreference = "Continue"
    $serverName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    $scriptPath = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    $logConfigPath = "$scriptPath/config.xml"



    #### VARIABLES RELATING TO THE LOG FILE

    #contains the log path and log file mask
    $logPaths = @()
    $logFileMasks = @()

    # the total number of lines grabbed from the end of the log file for evaluation
    $numLinesToTail = 1000

    # key value pair for the strings to match and the max count of matches before they are considered an issue
    $keywords = @()
    $maxCounts = @()



    #### VARIABLES RELATING TO THE EMAIL SETTINGS

    $smtpServer = "mail server"
    $emailSubject = "$serverName log report"
    $toEmailAddress = "email accounts"
    $fromEmailAddress = ""

    # any initial content you want in the email body should go here (e.g. the name of the server that this is on)
    $htmlBodyContent = "<p><h3>SERVER $serverName : </h3></p><p>Items that appear in red have exceeded their match threshold and should be investigated.<br/>Tail Lines: $numLinesToTail</p>"



    #### FUNCTION CALLS

    LoadLogTailerConfig $logConfigPath ([ref]$logPaths) ([ref]$logFileMasks) ([ref]$keywords) ([ref]$maxCounts)

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $logPaths.Count; $i++)
    {
        $tail = GetLogTail $numLinesToTail $logPaths[$i] $logFileMasks[$i]

        $tailIssueTable = CheckForKeywords $tail $keywords[$i] $maxCounts[$i]

        if ($tailIssueTable -ne "")
        { 
            $htmlBodyContent += "<br/>Logs scanned: " + (GetLatestLogFileFullName $logPaths[$i] $logFileMasks[$i]) + "<br/><br/>" + $tailIssueTable
            SendIssueEmail $smtpServer $emailSubject $toEmailAddress $ccEmailAddress $fromEmailAddress $htmlBodyContent
        }
    }
}

# Loads in configuration data for the utility to use
function LoadLogTailerConfig($logConfigPath, [ref]$logPaths, [ref]$logFileMasks, [ref]$keywords, [ref]$maxCounts)
{
    Write-Debug "Loading config file data from $logConfigPath"

    [xml]$configData = Get-Content $logConfigPath

    foreach ($log in $configData.Logs.Log) {

        $logPaths.Value += $log.FilePath
        $logFileMasks.Value += $log.FileMask

        $kwp = @()
        $kwc = @()

        foreach ($keywordSet in $log.Keywords.Keyword)
        {
            $kwp += $keywordSet.Pattern
            $kwc += $keywordSet.MaxMatches 
        }

        $keywords.Value += @(,$kwp)
        $maxCounts.Value += @(,$kwc)
    }
}

# Gets a string containing the last X lines of the most recent log file
function GetLogTail($numLinesToTail, $logPath, $logFileMask)
{
    $logFile = GetLatestLogFileFullName $logPath $logFileMask  #Get-ChildItem $logPath -Filter $logFileMask | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 1

    Write-Debug "Getting $numLinesToTail line tail of $logFile"

    $tail = Get-Content "$logFile" | select -Last $numLinesToTail

    return $tail
}

function GetLatestLogFileFullName($logPath, $logFileMask)
{
    $logFile = Get-ChildItem $logPath -Filter $logFileMask | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 1 

    return "$logPath$logFile"
}

# Returns body text for email containing details on keywords in the log file and their frequency
function CheckForKeywords($tail, $keywords, $maxCounts)
{   
    $issuesFound = 0

    $htmlBodyContent += "<table><tr><th style=""text-align : left;"">Keyword</th><th>Max Count Value</th><th>Count Total<th></tr>"

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $keywords.Count; $i++)
    {
        $keywordCount = ($tail | Select-String $keywords[$i] -AllMatches).Matches.Count

        Write-Debug (("Match count for {0} : {1}" -f $keywords[$i], $keywordCount))

        if ($keywordCount -gt $maxCounts[$i])
        {
            # style red if the count threshold has been exceeded
            $htmlBodyContent += "<tr style=""color : red;""><td>" + $keywords[$i] + "</td><td>" + $maxCounts[$i] + "</td><td>" + $keywordCount + "</td></tr>"
            $issuesFound = 1
        }
        else
        {
            # style green if the count threshold has not been exceeded
            $htmlBodyContent += "<tr style=""color : green;""><td>" + $keywords[$i] + "</td><td>" + $maxCounts[$i] + "</td><td>" + $keywordCount + "</td></tr>"
        }
    }

    $htmlBodyContent += "</table>"

    if ($issuesFound -eq 1)
    {
        return $htmlBodyContent
    }

    return ""
}

# Sends out an email to the specified email address
function SendIssueEmail($smtpServer, $subject, $toAddress, $ccAddress, $fromAddress, $bodyContent)
{
    Write-Debug "Sending email with subject: $subject, To: $toAddress, via SMTP ($smtpServer)"

    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Subject $subject -To $toAddress -From $fromAddress -BodyAsHtml $bodyContent
}

cls
Main
```

And a XML config example:

```
<Logs>
    <Log>
        <FilePath>C:/Some/Path</FilePath>
        <FileMask>log.*</FileMask>
        <Keywords>
            <Keyword>
                <Pattern>NullReferenceException</Pattern>
                <MaxMatches>10</MaxMatches>
            </Keyword>
            <Keyword>
                <Pattern>Exception</Pattern>
                <MaxMatches>10</MaxMatches>
            </Keyword>
        </Keywords>
    </Log>
    <Log>
        <FilePath>C:/Some/Path</FilePath>
        <FileMask>test.*</FileMask>
        <Keywords>
            <Keyword>
                <Pattern>NullReferenceException</Pattern>
                <MaxMatches>100</MaxMatches>
            </Keyword>
        </Keywords>
    </Log>
</Logs>
```

EDIT : The server that is having the issues is running Powershell V 1.0, however the test servers are also running the same version perfectly fine...

Comment: Is this all we need to reproduce your issue? If you suspect that versions might be a factor might be a good idea to include the versions in question.

Comment: At first glance, you could have issue with variable scopes. Newer versions of PoweShell (v3,v4) have stricter limitation on variable scope (my anecdotal experience only). In particular check that $keywords and $maxCounts are actually accessible in function LoadLogTailerConfig. This could vary depending on PowerShell version.

Comment: @JanChrbolka If this was the case though I shouldn't have any of the keywords getting matches, however some of them are getting matches whilst other keywords on the same lines are not being detected...

Comment: Can you add a short example log file to the question?

Comment: @JanChrbolka Probably not a great idea as it could pose a security risk, however they are fairly standard logs really, they have the following format :<TimeStamp> <LogType> <Message> where LogType is INFO ERROR DEBUG etc and Message contains either exception or other information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function GetLatestLogFileFullName is one problem. It can and will generate invalid paths.

```
function GetLatestLogFileFullName($logPath, $logFileMask)
{
    $logFile = Get-ChildItem $logPath -Filter $logFileMask | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 1 
    return "$logPath$logFile"
}
```

Use this instead:

```
return $logfile.FullName
```

And you should also check for cases where there is no valid log file:

```
if ($logfile) {
    return $logfile.FullName
} else {
    return $null
}
```

The second problem will be your Select-String usage.

```
$keywordCount = ($tail | Select-String $keywords[$i] -AllMatches).Matches.Count
```

In PowerShell v1 Select-String does not have -AllMatches parameter.

```
PS> Get-Help Select-String
NAME
    Select-String
SYNOPSIS
    Identifies patterns in strings.
SYNTAX
    Select-String [-pattern] <string[]> -inputObject <psobject>[-include <string[]>] [-exclude <string[]>] [-simpleMatch] [-caseSensitive] [-quiet] [-list] [<CommonParameters>]

    Select-String [-pattern] <string[]> [-path] <string[]> [-include<string[]>] [-exclude <string[]>] [-simpleMatch] [-caseSensitive] [-quiet] [-list] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Check the PowerShell versions on your servers using the $PSVersionTable variable. Do not rely on the version displayed in the title bar!

[image: PowerShell Version Confusion]

If the variable does not exist you have Version 1.

Comment: that is strange as we ran this on test servers and it worked perfectly fine, but it was only running 1.0, I will try and get an upgrade performed to see if it makes any kind of a difference.

Comment: Have you checked the version of PS using the $PSVersionTable variable? I have amended the answer.

Comment: I will check this out, I suspect that you have the correct answer to my issues though

Comment: it looks like the Test servers were running PS 3 whereas the production servers were running 2